# Pytest X dash 2.9.0: did not yield problem

Tags: python, pytest, plotly-dash

Just cannot run any pytest under dash 2.9.0:

error raised as:

```
wrap_controller at 'pytest_runtest_makereport' ..\Miniconda3\envs\myenv_39\lib\site-packages\dash\testing\plugin.py:106 did not yield
```

It's not comfortable if we downgrade dash to 2.8.X. Is it any methods to bypass this error?

Comment: No change. I found there are CI even need to downgrade dash to do pytest.